# nginx return 200 but empty reponse

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx

I am currently migrating apache to nginx and I am struggling to get it working.
Basically I get a 200 response with no content. My nginx configuration is as below:

```
server {

  listen   [::]:8749 default ipv6only=on;

  server_name localhost;

   location / {
    root /build/website;
    index status.php index.html index.htm;
   }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php7.4-fpm.sock;

    fastcgi_index status.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
  }



}
```

And here is `www.conf` file

```
[www]
; Replace the tcp listener and add the unix socket
listen = /var/run/php7.4-fpm.sock

; Ensure that the daemon runs as the correct user
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data


listen.mode = 0666

; Unix user of FPM processes
user = www-data
group = www-data

; Choose process manager type (static, dynamic, ondemand)
pm = ondemand
pm.max_children = 16
```

`fastcgi_params`

```
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_SCHEME     $scheme;
fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
```

My URL is something like:

```
/r.php?format=json&a=1&e=1&zoom=17
```

PHP files are on `/build/website` directory and it is primarily an API site, no static or HTML files.

Is there anything obvious I am missing?

Many thanks.
Cheers,
Vini

Comment: Why do you put `root` and `index` directives into the `location` context rather than `server` one?

Comment: I've tried both approaches and none worked.

Comment: Show your `fastcgi_params` file contents.

Comment: Just added as part of the question in the main body the details of fastcgi_params and www.conf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have the `SCRIPT_FILENAME` FastCGI parameter defined. Add the

```
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

directive to your PHP handler `location` block. Additionally, that `location` block uses the default nginx root instead of `/build/website` one, move the `root` directive to the `server` context.

Comment: I tried before similar to what you mentioned but I get a "No input file specified" error: server {
  listen   [::]:8749 default ipv6only=on;
  root /build/website;
  server_name localhost;
  location / {
    index status.php index.html index.htm;
  }
  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index status.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
  }
}

Comment: So you have the `r.php` file under the `/build/website` directory and you get that message trying the `http://localhost:8749/r.php?format=json&a=1&e=1&zoom=17` URL? Any other `server` blocks defined in your config?

Comment: Any errors reporting via `nginx -t` command? Additionally, `default` flag on `listen` directive was renamed to `default_server` years ago, try to change that one.

Comment: Yes, calling that url I was getting "no input file specified". I changed the fastcgi_params to fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME `$document_root$fastcgi_script_name` and the error changed to access denied. Log: [error] 1943#1943: *2 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Access to the script '`/build/website/r.php`' has been denied (see security.limit_extensions)" while reading response header from upstream, client: ::1, server: localhost, request: "GET /r.php?format=json&a=1&e=1&zoom=17 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php7.4-fpm.sock:", host: "localhost:8749"

Comment: Do you have correct owner/permissions on your PHP files? User `www-data` had to have at least read access to those files.

Comment: www-data does have access to build/website. Is there anything to set on security.limit_extensions?

Comment: The `security.limit_extensions` option is designed to limit allowed extensions for files containing the PHP code. The `.php` file extension should be allowed in any case unless you made some changes to that parameter by yourself. What is your host OS? Maybe you have some additional security layer like SELinux enabled?

Comment: Using Ubuntu 20.10. I haven't done any changes to any security. It started with clean install and apache+mpm_prefork. As performance proved not to be good, I added nginx and disabled apache but for some strange reason I can't get a response from it.